# Random position of span with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have seven span with text. How can I set random position of this spans? I want to set random position without overlapping and without exiting the edge.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <style>
.picture{
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    position:absolute;
}

.cont {
    position:relative;
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
</style>    

    <body>
        <div class="cont">
        <input type="text" id="i_file1" name="i_file" class="textField">
        <input type="text" id="i_file2" name="i_file" class="textField">
        <input type="text" id="i_file3" name="i_file" class="textField">
        <input type="text" id="i_file4" name="i_file" class="textField">
        <input type="text" id="i_file5" name="i_file" class="textField">
        <input type="text" id="i_file6" name="i_file" class="textField">
        <input type="text" id="i_file7" name="i_file" class="textField">



        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <button onclick="textFields()" id="texttt"> text </button>
        <button id="losuj" onclick="reset()">reset </button>

    </body>

    <script>

        function textFields() {

            $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {

                var id  = $(this).attr("id");
                id = "#" + id;
                var value1 = $(id).val();
                var html_code = '<br/><br/><span class="blabla">' + value1 + '</span>';
                $(id).after(html_code);
                $(id).hide();
            });

            $("#texttt").hide();

        }



function reset() {

        var containerW = 300;
        var containerH = 300;


        $('.blabla').each(function() {

         var x = parseInt(Math.random() * (containerW-$(this).width()));
         var y = parseInt(Math.random() * (containerH-$(this).height()));   

            $(this).css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: x + 'px',
                left: y + 'px'
            });
        });
    }



    </script>


</html>
```

My code for now, I set position to random, but I don't know how to do this with overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

OK This is my solution, 
with TOP attribute:
I split the div to (300/20) = 15 parts -- we can call as rows
So when the first span display, then it will take one random element
in ps[] and the rest can not get this element, do the same to rest
with LEFT attribute:
I set random LEFT from 0 to the point which the div can include the span
=> I make sure that they never get overlap 
Hope it help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <style>
.picture{
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    position:absolute;
}

.cont {
    position:relative;
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
</style>    

    <body>
 <button id="losuj" onclick="random()">
        Random
        </button><BR><BR>
        <div class="cont">
        <input type="text" id="i_file1" name="i_file" class="textField">
        <input type="text" id="i_file2" name="i_file" class="textField">
        <input type="text" id="i_file3" name="i_file" class="textField">
        <input type="text" id="i_file4" name="i_file" class="textField">
        <input type="text" id="i_file5" name="i_file" class="textField">
        <input type="text" id="i_file6" name="i_file" class="textField">
        <input type="text" id="i_file7" name="i_file" class="textField">





       

    </body>

    <script>
function getRandomInteger(min, max) {
  min = Math.floor(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  var rd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  return rd;
}



function random() {
        var ps= [];
        var n = 0;
        var containerW = 300;
        var containerH = 300;
        var spanW;
        var spanH;
        var first = true;
        var first_H ;
        var current_H ;
      for(var i=0; i< 15; i++)
      {
        ps[i] = i;
      }
      $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
if(first)
{
  spanW = $(this).width();
  spanH = $(this).height();
  first = false
 }
  var x = getRandomInteger(0,containerW-spanW);
  var p = getRandomInteger(0,ps.length-1);
  var y = ps[p]*20;
  ps.splice(p, 1);
  $(this).css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: y + 'px',
    left: x + 'px'
  });
});
}
    


    </script>


</html>
```

Comment: it would improve and make the answer more helpful to the OP if you specify what corrections have you made.

Comment: OK, I put the first span without checking overlap, then base on its TOP I restrict the TOP of rest. And about the LEFT I allow them move from 0 to 300. It's so simple!